# Is there a way (in Vmware) to open a Host-file with a Guest App from the Host computer?

Tags: vmware

I'm planning to install Visual Studio (for editing .aspx files) in a guest VM.

If I'm working in the Host computer, is there a way to open a file on that Host with a program  in the Guest VM?

Comment: Are you planning to use VMware Workstation or VMWare ESX?

Comment: Vmware Workstation and Player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Shared folder](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html) feature for access to files on a host machine from Guest VM. To use this feature you should install the [VMware tools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=340) on Guest VM. After setting up the Shared folder, you can access files on the host in a path like “\.host\Shared Folders\Test files”.

To send a command to open file on Guest OS from the host you could use `vmrun` utility, which helps you manage virtual machines from command line (for more detail see [this official manual](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix112_vmrun_command.pdf) and examples in “Running Guest Applications”). On the other hand, you could just open a VM console and run script manually :)

In addition, I don't recommend to install Visual Studio on Guest VM. The Visual Studio will always execute faster on the host. Moreover, you will be more convenient to work with snapshots and few VMs. In this case, you could use remote debugging tools for debug and automatically deploy your application on Guest VM after build.

Comment: You might be able to have a shortcut on the Host that executes an exe on the Guest and then, from the Host, right click on a file and choose "open with" and choose the shortcut above.  (I decided to install VS locally instead of in a Guest VM so I wont' be testing this for now.)